# Regplot com ano no eixo X (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Estou tentando plotar um gráfico de regressão em que o intervalo de data seja no formato de ano, porém não consigo centralizar os dados o eixo X.
O intervalo do gráfico abaixo está entre 2016 e 2020.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(13,9))
ax = sns.regplot(data=dados_de_carga, x='data_ordinal', y='media_carga',scatter_kws={"color": "black"},line_kws={"color": "red"})

# Tighten up the axes for prettiness
ax.set_xlim(dados_de_carga['data_ordinal'].min() - 2, dados_de_carga['data_ordinal'].max() + 2)
ax.set_ylim(0, dados_de_carga['media_carga'].max() + 2)

ax.set_xlabel('')
new_labels = dados_de_carga['data_de_distribuicao'].dt.strftime('%Y')
ax.set_xticklabels(new_labels)
plt.ylabel('Média de carga')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

O `ax.set_xticklabels` aceita como argumento um vetor com os labels a serem exibidos no eixo x, mas caso esse vetor seja maior que o vetor com os `handles`, então só os primeiros nomes são utilizados.

No seu caso, se você tem a garantia que a localização dos pontos da legenda está correta, basta fazer

```
newlabels = [str(ano) for ano in range(2016, 2021)]
```